# operator [] list cpp

Tags: c++, list

My list class is using operator[].Can i use this override class. If there is any reason for not providing operator[] for list, please explain. If there is any mistake in code below Please clear it.

```
template<class _Ty,class _Ax = std::allocator<_Ty>>  class listadv : public  
std::list<_Ty,_Ax>
{
// should declare in top of the class
public:
    _Ty operator[](int index)
{
    std::list<_Ty,_Ax>::iterator iter = this->begin();
    std::advance(iter, index);
    return *iter;
}
};
```

Defined in header class.

Comment: Public inheritance from a standard container is never a good thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for not providing `std::list<T>::operator[]` is that it it would not be of O(1) complexity but rather of O(N). If you are using a linked list, you should structure your algorithms in a way that does not involve indexed access.

I suggest against the `listadv` class like you propose in OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have access like this, implement it as a templated function (like `get_nth`).

Additionally, your `operator[]`. You should always provide two variants, a non-const one returning a non-const reference and a const variant returning a const reference. You should never return the element by value, since that will make the expression `a[i] = 5` fail in a very subtle way (i.e. without a compiler error).

I think this C++11 code should work as expected:

```
template <typename Container>
auto get_nth(Container& c, std::size_t n) -> decltype(*c.begin())
{
     auto iter = c.begin();
     std::advance(iter, n);
     return *iter;
}

// ...

std::list<int> l;
// ...
get_nth(l, 3) = 1;
```